# What is a "slider interrupt" on Android

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I feel like an idiot for having to ask this question, but I have no idea what a slider interrupt is on Android, and a search of Google and Stackoverflow turned up nothing. Amazon sent me a rejection notice for my app because all of the activities except the main one (which they call, "pop up windows") do not respond well to a slider interrupt. I have no seekbars anywhere in the app, so that isn't the "slider" that they are referring to.

Also, one of the views in question isn't a new activity at all, but a listview. It disappears on a "slider interrupt." As far as I know, I have no control over what a listview dialog does in this case. Once I figure out what a slider interrupt is, how do I tell the listview not to close when it happens? I suppose I could track whether the listview is open and recall in onResume or whatever function handles slider interrupts. But without knowing what a slider interrupt is, it makes testing difficult.

Comment: There is no such term in Android, so it is some term peculiar to Amazon's review team. So, you will need to ask them.

Comment: Yeah, I sent them an email but they take a few days to respond and I was hoping to resolve the situation sooner.

Comment: Just another guess into the blue. With conventional mobile phones there where build types like slider, bar, clamshell etc. Maybe it refers to a slider like the keyboard in the Droid/Milestone, Vision, Desire Z etc. (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with Amazon. I filed a ticket and here is the response:

> A slider interrupt occurs on devices with a flip-out keyboard. While the app is running the keyboard is flipped out.

Comment: Yep, they got back to me too and that was it. Seems obvious in hindsight. But I have no idea why they feel the need to make up their own terms. Saying, 'open the hardware keyboard' is just as easy as saying, 'trigger a slider interrupt' and everyone understands it. If they want to use technical terms, they should have called it a configuration change.